# @withRouter Unexpected Token Error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

Seems every time I have to setup React Router in a new project I run into something new possibly by version changes.

I am using reactjs and mobx state tree(though at this point have not used anything of it).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HomeComponent from './HomeComponent.js';
import {withRouter, Route} from 'react-router'

@withRouter
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Route exact path='/' component={HomeComponent}/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I run it I get

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError /components/App.js: Unexpected token (6:0)
```

I also get some warning as well

```
 Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

Edit

Per the comment from "Artem Mirchenko"

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider  } from 'mobx-react';
import { useStrict } from 'mobx';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {syncHistoryWithStore } from 'mobx-react-router';
import { Router } from 'react-router'

import AppContainer from './components/App';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

import stores from '../src/stores/Stores';

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, stores.routingStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {... stores}>
        <Router history={history}>
           <AppContainer />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,      
       document.getElementById('app')
);

import {RouterStore} from 'mobx-react-router';

const routingStore = new RouterStore();
const stores = {
    routingStore
}

export default stores;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install babel plugin `transform-decorators-legacy`.

Via yarn:

```
yard add --dev transform-decorators-legacy
```

Vie npm:

```
npm install --save-dev transform-decorators-legacy
```

And add in to plugins ket in you babel options:

```
{
 // pressets ....
 "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Comment: Right, was so convinced it was routing issue. I also did "transform-class-properties". Do you know how experimental @withRouter is? I guess I should also be referencing react-router-dom instea of react-router

Comment: Looks your code, i think is not necessary to use withRouter, you can simply use BrowserRoter. Here is a great and simple example: [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Comment: Maybe, I am not sure. I am copying an old project. In that project I am using Browser History. Might be because I am also referencing mobx router. as well. I will post that code up here and then decide if it warrants a new questions.

Comment: It is ok, so naw you can wrap your <AppContainer> in <Router /> and attach browser history to him.  See here is another example [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)

Comment: Ok, then what I have seems to be good then, I just looking at how to make it so if I copy the url now it does not give me and error "Cannot GET /something/". I thought devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  } fixed this issue, but does not seem to be working

Comment: Try add  `publicPath: '/'` in `output` section of webpack config file, it s help in my case.